# How can we set a variable such that it can be used in a different test suite?

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to set an variable in testSuite#1. Use the above variable in testSuite#2.

Do we have any keywords to do it? Can we export it at command line?

Comment: You could write it to a file from `testSuite#1` and read it into `testSuite#2`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very good idea, because you end up with a dependency between two suites, and a dependency on the order that the suites are run.

That being said, there are a couple of ways you can accomplish this.

#### Using Set Global Variable

The first method is to use the [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) keyword from the built-in library.

```
| | Set global variable | ${foobar} | this is foobar
```

#### Setting an environment varible

The second way would be to set an [environment variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#environment-variables) that can be shared between two suites, using the [OperatingSystem](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html) library.

suite1.robot

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Operating System

*** Test Case ***
| Save a variable that other suites can see
| | Set environment variable | foobar | this is foobar
```

suite2.robot

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
| Use a variable from another suite
| | Should be equal | %{foobar} | this is foobar
```

Notice the use of `%` instead of `$` to access the variable. You can also use [Get Environment Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20Environment%20Variable) to get the value of one or more variables.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I would rather use the "global variable" mentioned by ombre42 in the other answer. Env. variable make the variable available to the other processes which is not useful in that case I guess.

Comment: @LaurentBristiel: you are correct, though it would only make it available to processes spawned by the test.

Answer (score 3):

Use BuiltIn's [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable). This should be avoided whenever possible, but is sometimes necessary.

```
Set Global Variable    ${MYPROJ_ADMIN_PASSWORD}    supersecret123
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snipped code sample-

```
*** Settings ***
Library     BuiltIn

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    .....
    ${test}=    ${temp}
    Set Global Variable      ${test} 
TC2    
    Log to Console    \n Global variable value is ${test}
```

Reference: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html

Answer (score 0):

If you plan a large project and need to maintain many variables/parameters for different variants we solve this with:

PyPI:
[robotframework-testsuitesmanagement](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-testsuitesmanagement/)

Documentation:
[robotframework-testsuitesmanagement documentation](https://github.com/test-fullautomation/robotframework-testsuitesmanagement/blob/develop/RobotFramework_TestsuitesManagement/RobotFramework_TestsuitesManagement.pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).