# Pass variables from one test case to another in Robot framework (Global variable)

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables, automated-tests, robotframework

I have one test suit with two test cases. I have one same-name variable between the two test cases, let's say `${X}`. The first test case changes the value of this variable. The second test case, gives me the following error `Variable '${X}' not found`.

**How can I have something like a Global Variable?** Like if it is defined in one test case, the next test case will recognize this variable and use the new value and so on

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25386974/7432

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this,when ever you are trying to change the value of variable then make that variable Global, this meets your requirement so when the variables are logged in the below example it has the latest value stored in the variable.

```
    *** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${test}=    Evaluate    9
    Set Global Variable      ${test} 
Test2
    ${test}=    Evaluate    10
    Set Global Variable      ${test} 
Test
    Log Variables
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably need a suite level variable to share the value across the tests. From your description it is not clear if your tests are under the same test suites or different.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's partially what I wanted. As if in test1 for example I make `set suite variable  ${X} 5` then **only** this value of `5` will be recognized by the next test. I mean if `${X}` changes after declaration as a suit variable to `3` for example, then the next test case will only recognize `${X}` as `5` and **not** as `3`

Comment: I am not sure if I get you correctly , Set Suite Variable and Set Global Variable are the two builtin keywords with which you can access variables across the tests. Though Set Global Variable comes with a bit of caution, I believe that is what you might be needing. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable. You can also define a python module with your global variables and use it.